# Open website with picture (based on link)

Tags: javascript, html, image, web

I want to make one website (running on a Raspberry Pi) and based on the link (for example: test.com/01 or test.com/02) the exact website should be opened, but with another picture. I want to avoid a database and I would like to work with pictures. Is it possible always to open the "index.html" website and get the numbers out of the link?

Comment: Go for it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: You shared your plans and preferences, but forgot to ask your questions.

Comment: You can just make 2 directories, whose html file has a simple background image. You can also make the images as 01.jpg and 02.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test.com/01` will take you to the 01 file. What you are trying to do is pass in key-value query parameters, and need a [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) like this `test.com?picture=01`. You can even use the same HTML page and then [choose the picture from the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Since you want to avoid DBs, you can send both pictures and then hide the one that is not in the query string.

URLs are kinda complicated, [check them out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this might help to solve my problem :)

Comment: Happy to help. I appreciate you accepted the answer, can I also get a sweet, sweet upvote?